# How do I position buttons or text boxes or labels using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple GUI program with python 3 using `tkinter`. I need help moving labels, buttons, or entry boxes to different positions on the GUI.

```
lbl_title = tkinter.Label(root, text="Welcome to the Guessing Game!", bg="white") 
lbl_title.pack()
```

Comment: You can get an answer to this question from any tkinter tutorial. Why do you need to ask here?

Answer (score 0):

Try grid

```
root = Tk()

l1 = Label(root, text="peace")
l1.grid(row=0, column=1)
```